# Geom_label_repel not properly referencing to the sec.axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel, geom

I am working with a `ggplot` that has two axis: one for the `geom_bar` component, and the other for the `geom_line`component. And for this, I am using the `sec.axis()` command.

I wanted to insert a box to provide the last value of the `geom_line` component, but I am struggling because I believe that while using the commmand `geom_label_repel`, the aesthetic being used, is referent to the `geom_bar`component.

I'll provide a similar data to illustrate what I am saying.

```
df <- data.frame(day = as.character(seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 1)),
             total = rbinom(n=100,30,0.5), 
             prop = runif(100))

df <- df %>% arrange(df, by = day)
df$`percentage` <- label_percent(accuracy = 0.01)(df$prop)


ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = day, y = total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightgreen", width = 0.35) + 
  geom_line(data = df, 
            aes(x = day, y = (prop)*15, group = 1), 
            color = "red", size = 1,inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous( 
    labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE),
    #breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10000000,by = 100000),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./15, 
                        name = "Secondary axis",
                        breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.1),
                        scales::percent))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+
  geom_label_repel(data=df[nrow(df),], 
                   aes(x = day, 
                       y = prop*1,
                       label = round(prop*100,2)),
                   color = 'red',
                   segment.alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 7)))
```

Which outputs the following image:

[image: example]

As you can tell, it works well in regards to obtaining the last number of the `prop` column, which is intended, but it is not automatically placed beside the `geom_line`.
I have tried messing with the `nudge_x`and `nudge_y` commands but it didn't lead me to anywhere, given the fact that I want to have this "number placement" automatic.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sec.axis` is in some ways just decorative. `ggplot` is plotting everything by the main axis. To make the label follow the line, make the same transform as in your `geom_line` call (`y = prop*15`):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
df <- data.frame(day = as.character(seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 1)),
                 total = rbinom(n=100,30,0.5), 
                 prop = runif(100))

df <- df %>% arrange(df, by = day)
df$`percentage` <- scales::label_percent(accuracy = 0.01)(df$prop)


ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = day, y = total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightgreen", width = 0.35) + 
  geom_line(data = df, 
            aes(x = day, y = (prop)*15, group = 1), 
            color = "red", size = 1,inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous( 
    labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE),
    #breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10000000,by = 100000),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./15, 
                        name = "Secondary axis",
                        breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.1),
                        scales::percent))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+
  geom_label_repel(data=df[nrow(df),], 
                   aes(x = day, 
                       y = prop*15,
                       label = round(prop*100,2)),
                   color = 'red',
                   segment.alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 7)))
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

[image]

Comment: That was the only thing missing, totally slipped my mind! Thank you, problem solved ;)